# Error while running openrewrite UpgradeSpringBoot_3_0

Tags: spring-boot, openrewrite

I upgraded my repo to 2.7.1 using UpgradeSpringBoot_2_7 and project built successfully.

Now when i try to upgrade to SpringBoot 3.0.x , rewrite:run fails with error :

***Unexpected EOF in prolog
at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]***

I don't find any issue with pom as mvn clean install does not fail.

Java version : 11

please help fix this issue

followed https://docs.openrewrite.org/reference/recipes/java/spring/boot3/upgradespringboot_3_0

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:4.43.0:run (default-cli) on project nss-settlement-rest-service: Execution default-cli of goal org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:4.43.0:run failed: Failed to parse pom: Unexpected EOF in prolog
[ERROR]  at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:4.43.0:run (default-cli) on project nss-settlement-rest-service: Execution default-cli of goal org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:4.43.0:run failed: Failed to parse pom
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:578)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:4.43.0:run failed: Failed to parse pom
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:578)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: Failed to parse pom
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.RawPom.parse (RawPom.java:113)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.download (MavenPomDownloader.java:505)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom.resolveDependencies (ResolvedPom.java:595)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom.resolveDependencies (ResolvedPom.java:518)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.MavenResolutionResult.resolveDependencies (MavenResolutionResult.java:179)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenParser.parseInputs (MavenParser.java:107)
    at org.openrewrite.Parser.parse (Parser.java:41)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenMojoProjectParser.parseMaven (MavenMojoProjectParser.java:363)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteMojo.listResults (AbstractRewriteMojo.java:276)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteRunMojo.execute (AbstractRewriteRunMojo.java:54)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:578)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._initializeXmlReader (XmlFactory.java:717)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createParser (XmlFactory.java:583)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createParser (XmlFactory.java:30)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser (JsonFactory.java:1083)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue (ObjectMapper.java:3666)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.RawPom.parse (RawPom.java:107)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.download (MavenPomDownloader.java:505)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom.resolveDependencies (ResolvedPom.java:595)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom.resolveDependencies (ResolvedPom.java:518)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.MavenResolutionResult.resolveDependencies (MavenResolutionResult.java:179)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenParser.parseInputs (MavenParser.java:107)
    at org.openrewrite.Parser.parse (Parser.java:41)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenMojoProjectParser.parseMaven (MavenMojoProjectParser.java:363)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteMojo.listResults (AbstractRewriteMojo.java:276)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteRunMojo.execute (AbstractRewriteRunMojo.java:54)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:578)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF (StreamScanner.java:701)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleEOF (BasicStreamReader.java:2235)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog (BasicStreamReader.java:2141)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next (BasicStreamReader.java:1180)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._initializeXmlReader (XmlFactory.java:712)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createParser (XmlFactory.java:583)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createParser (XmlFactory.java:30)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser (JsonFactory.java:1083)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue (ObjectMapper.java:3666)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.RawPom.parse (RawPom.java:107)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.download (MavenPomDownloader.java:505)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom.resolveDependencies (ResolvedPom.java:595)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom.resolveDependencies (ResolvedPom.java:518)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.MavenResolutionResult.resolveDependencies (MavenResolutionResult.java:179)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenParser.parseInputs (MavenParser.java:107)
    at org.openrewrite.Parser.parse (Parser.java:41)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenMojoProjectParser.parseMaven (MavenMojoProjectParser.java:363)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteMojo.listResults (AbstractRewriteMojo.java:276)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteRunMojo.execute (AbstractRewriteRunMojo.java:54)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:578)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :nss-settlement-rest-service
~/IdeaProjects/repo/nss-settlement-rest feature/SPN-976-migrate-to-spring-boot-3
```

Comment: Hi! We're going to need a few more details before we're able to help you. How much of your `pom.xml` are you able to share? And can you create a reproduction project?

Comment: The error seems to hint at potentially parsing an empty stream; which makes it hard to pin down, as there's little to go on. Could you run the command again with `--debug` such that there's perhaps more of a stacktrace to help debug?

Comment: Added the failing pom.

Comment: @Tim The same issue does not happen if i migrate from 2.4.3 to 3.0.x directly using the UpgradeSpringBoot_3_0

Comment: Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF (StreamScanner.java:701)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleEOF (BasicStreamReader.java:2235)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog (BasicStreamReader.java:2141)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next (BasicStreamReader.java:1180)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._initializeXmlReader (XmlFactory.java:712)

Comment: Hi Dinesh; thanks for adding the stacktrace; can you also share (part of) your pom.xml? If you'd rather share that in private you're always welcome in our public Slack channel as well; via the link at the top of https://docs.openrewrite.org

Comment: When replicating with the supplied pom.xml files locally it appears some pom files in `~/.m2/repository` contain HTML instead of XML; that might be the source of issues here. You could try removing all invalid POM files, and double check that your selected repositories only return valid XML responses.

Comment: After deleting and recreating the ~/.m2/repository , issue got resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deleting and recreating the ~/.m2/repository , issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Accoring to the "Preparing for Spring Boot 3.0" docs:

```
Spring Boot 3.0 will require Java 17
```

So maybe, since you mention Java 11, this is your problem?

Comment: Hi,java version will be updated to 17 automatically when 3.0 recipe is ran.recreating ~/.m2/repository resolved issue

Comment: I'm using gradle, and it doesn't update dependency versions either :-(

Comment: Feel free to open up an issue for that @jeremyt!

Comment: Thanks @Tim. I'm putting togther a demo project that highlights issues I experience migrating from SB 2.7 to 3.0. On one hand I'm quite busy (aren't we all), and on the other I actually feel bad about raising an issue with what is a truly amazing product!

Comment: Don't feel bad reporting an issue; any improvements made will make things even better for the next people using the affected recipes. Feel free to drop by our Slack if you'd like some guidance on how to best report issues; anything related to a specific recipe for instance likely could use another unit test to reproduce.